# Visual Studio Default Button Properties

Tags: .net, winforms

I am building an application with a few buttons, I would like to keep the entire style, apart from the text, so I can re use it without having to remake the button.

Is there a way to change the default button style so when I add a new button it takes those properties or will it have to be coded?

I am sure I can push the button style through but was wondering if VS has the capabilities.

Comment: Why has this question been voted to close as too localized? This is a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a button of your own, as a user control, and then create buttons that use (inherit) your custom-made button.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a collection of the buttons and then use a foreach loop to set the style you wish to mirror.  (Apologies, I don't have access to an IDE right now so, this is just from the hip).

```
foreach (Button btn in btnCollection)
{
      btn.Text = "";
      btn.BackColor = "Whatever color you like";
}
```

Or, you could also create a user control and inherit from it.